# Fixing Macro for Filtering

Tags: excel, vba, printing

I have this macro to filter a worksheet but right now it is assuming the headrs are only in row 1... how do i have it assume headers are rows 1-4? (aka the filter starts on row 4)

This is basically to filter a table and save them as  a PDF in one of our files

```
Dim TempWks As Worksheet
Dim wks As Worksheet

Dim myRng As Range
Dim myCell As Range

'change to match your worksheet name
Set wks = Worksheets("Sheet3")

Set TempWks = Worksheets.Add

wks.AutoFilterMode = False 'remove the arrows

'assumes headers only in row 1
wks.Columns(1).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CopyToRange:=TempWks.Range("A1"), Unique:=True

With TempWks
    Set myRng = .Range("a4", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
End With

With wks
    For Each myCell In myRng.Cells
        .UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=myCell.Value
Dim MyFileName As Variant
Dim MyfilePath As Variant

MyfilePath = "xxx" 'File Location

MyFileName = MyfilePath & "\" & myCell.Value & ".pdf" 'File Name

    ChDir _
    MyfilePath


wks.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
  MyFileName, Quality:= _
     xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
  OpenAfterPublish:=False
    Next myCell
End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
TempWks.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: Perhaps the cause was the use of `.UsedRange`. If it's always from 4th row, then try   replace the `.UsedRange.AutoFilter...` with `Intersect(.UsedRange, .UsedRange.Offset(4,0)).AutoFilter...`

Comment: This worked :) thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
With wks.Range(wks.Cells(4,1), wks.Cells(rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    .AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
                    CopyToRange:=TempWks.Range("A1"), Unique:=True
End With
```

Comment: It was erroring out lower on the macro. Patrick's fix was able to help :)

Thanks for the input

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the cause was the use of .UsedRange. If it's always from 4th row, then try replace the .UsedRange.AutoFilter... with Intersect(.UsedRange, .UsedRange.Offset(4,0)).AutoFilter...

Comment: Hi Michael you are not supposed to write this comment like an answer. Can you delete it and write as an comment?